# how does the BertModel know to skip attention_mask argument when applied to a single sentence?

Tags: bert-language-model, attention-model

I am creating a class which can generate sentence embedding for both a single sentence and a list of sentences using pretrained BertModel. From a sample code, I see the statement

```
outputs = self.model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)
```

which is without the attention_mask argument. Yet it produces the same result if I do input the attention mask tensor argument

```
outputs = self.model(tokens_tensor, attention_tensors, segments_tensors)
```

When running the code for an entire dataset, then the attention_tensors is absolutely needed.

I understand the reason for not needing attention mask for a single sentence, but how does the python code know the second argument is actually segments_tensor, since in the document, it is expecting attention_tensors to be the second argument.

https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html

Answer (score 0):

If the `attention_mask` is not set (and is thus `None`), is explicitly set to ones everywhere.

See [l. 803 in `modeling_bert.py`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L803).

Comment: I am glad to see the referenced lines, but my original question remains a curiosity. both attention_mask and segment_id are optional parameterized arguments. If you don't feed the attention_mask, and go straight to the segment_id, how does the the model.forward() function know to interpret the second argument as segment_id and not attention_mask?